# copy one particular data from multiple remote servers and copy the the same on C drive of the server as a backup

Tags: powershell

I need to take a backup of an xml file from multiple remote servers and the same backup must b e copied on all remote servers C drive.And I was trying to do the same something like below .

Can anyone help me here to correct this please ?

```
 ForEach ($Computer in Get-Content C:\servers.txt)
{
       $file = get-childitem "c:\clusterstorage\*.xml*"-Recurse
       Invoke-Command -AsJob -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command "Copy-Item -Path '\\$Computer\$file' -Destination '\\$Computer\C:\'"}                             
}
```

Comment: You can directly use the copy-item inside the loop. You do not need to use invoke-expression on the context.

Comment: I have tried that, but the file is not getting copied

Comment: Thanks Ranadip. I have edited little bit and worked

Comment: Let me put it as an answer. Acceptance would be appreciable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use the `copy-item` inside the loop. You do not need to use invoke-expression on the context.
It should work then.